# Definition of $A\subset B$ for operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, operator-theory

Quick trivial question that I did not find an answer to immediately from a textbook, so good material for stackexchange.

In operator theory what does it mean for an operator to be a subset of other operator e.g. $A \subset B$? We are considering dense operators, as bonus does this mean the range, domain or both are dense?

Comment: I think this depends on the context, but I would guess it refers to the graphs. What book/article are you reading?

Comment: So, practically everything in most constructions of mathematics (e.g. ZF) are technically sets under the hood.  This includes functions and operators.  A function (*equivalently, an operator*) is a subset of $X\times Y$ satisfying certain special properties where $X$ is called the "domain" of the function and $Y$ the "codomain" of the function.  As such, looking at a subset of a function is perfectly valid.  In practice, this might be described as "restricting the domain of the function" and yields a new function on a smaller domain which agrees with the first for each value on that domain.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is actually quite simple. When we write $A\subset B,$ what we mean is that the graph of $A$ is a subset of the graph of $B$. In particular, if $A:D(A)\subset H\rightarrow H$ and $B:D(B)\subset H\rightarrow H,$ then we mean that $D(A)\subset D(B)$ and $Ax=Bx$ for all $x\in D(A).$